# How to resize / stretch World Space UI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas

I have some canvases with sliders and buttons with World Space render mode in my 3d game. Canvases attached to different game objects at different distances from each other.

How can I resize canvases depending on the zoom in or out of the Camera?

Importat! All canvases must do this at the same time.

For example: Canvas should shrink when Camera zoom in or stretch when zoom out.

For now I make it like this (but it seems to me there is a better way):

```
 if (Vector3.Distance(_camera.transform.position, transform.position) < 70)
 {
    var scaleFactor = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), 0.01f);
    transform.localScale = scaleFactor;
  }
  else
  { 
    //Because default canvas scale is 1, 1, 1
    var scaleFactor = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, Vector3.one, 0.01f);
    transform.localScale = scaleFactor;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just asking, you can use canvas with overlay screen or overlay camera, it will always be on your screen with screen size no matter you zoom in or zoom out or you slide.
Or you can make a parent game object with two childrens in it. One children being the gameobject the canvas is attached to and another being the canvas and apply transform on the parent, It will also work for both the children I guess.